# Javascript how to prevent adding HTML elements to DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Say I have the following HTML source:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="myscript.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script>/*other script*/</script> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" ...> 
  </head>
  <body>
   <div>...</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

What does myscript.js code look like to **prevent** adding DOM elements as if source code was originally?

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="myscript.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

I already tried overriding javascript DOM manipulation methods such as `.append`, `.prepend`, `.appendChild`, `.inserBefore`, etc, for all nodes. Still, the browser adds `<meta>`, `<script>`, `<link>`, `<div>`, and so on. It seems javascript overrides only affects javascript created nodes... which makes sense IMO.

The question is: is there a way to prevent adding DOM items which are part of the download HTML source?

Comment: why are you trying to do this? what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [`Window.stop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/stop):

> The window.stop() stops further resource loading in the current browsing context, equivalent to the stop button in the browser.
>
> Because of how scripts are executed, this method cannot interrupt its parent document's loading, but it will stop its images, new windows, and other still-loading objects.

Here's an example:

```html
<div>Div #1</div>
<p>Paragraph #1</p>
<div>Div #2</div>
<script>
  window.stop();
</script>
<p>Paragraph #2</p><!-- This element is not rendered -->
```